# LinkedHashMap from JSON returns null on get()

Tags: java, android

I build a `LinkedHashMap<Byte, Integer>` from JSON.
When I log the entries, they are here, but when I call `get()` (40 for example), it returns null.
Where I'm wrong ?

```
    String json = "{\"0\":0,\"34\":0,\"36\":0,\"38\":0,\"40\":3}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    LinkedHashMap<Byte, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map = gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());

    for (Map.Entry<Byte, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "item[" + entry.getKey() + "] = " + entry.getValue());
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "map.get(40) = " + map.get(40));
```

Output :

```
item[0] = 0.0
item[34] = 0.0
item[36] = 0.0
item[38] = 0.0
item[40] = 3.0
map.get(40) = null
```

Comment: Note that hash map use `hashCode()` and `equals()` and 40 is an `int` literal (so boxed to `Integer`). Now have a look at whether a `Byte` and an `Integer` would be considered equal (hint: both implementations of `equals()` use `instanceof` to check whether both are of the same type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that the types of keys are not `Byte` - they are `String`. Just because you cast, doesn't mean library will deserialize it correctly, it doesn't look at the java types you declared, but at the second argument to `fromJson`, which is just a `LinkedHashMap` with no generics in this case.

So basically: `map.get("40");`.

And to have it correctly deserialized to `Byte`, you can:

```java
LinkedHashMap<Byte, Integer> map = gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(LinkedHashMap.class, Byte.class, Integer.class).getType());
System.out.println("map.get(40) = " + map.get((byte)40));
```